# Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

This is difficult situation to explain. Have a service process that starts 2 threads, each thread loops forever but sleeps for 5 minutes each once the payload is finished.

Problem is that my second thread terminates well before the payload is even finished, for no apparent reason, and i also can't catch the exception as it seems to be triggered from outside the delegate process?

Any suggestions on how to find the problem?

The code....

```
public void StartService()
{
  ThreadStart stRecieve = new ThreadStart(DownloadNewMail);
  ThreadStart stSend = new ThreadStart(SendNewMail);
  senderThread = new Thread(stRecieve);
  recieverThread = new Thread(stSend);

  sendStarted = true;
  recieveStarted = true;

  senderThread.Start();
  recieverThread.Start();
}

private void DownloadNewMail()
{
  while(recieveStarted)
  {
    //Payload....

    if (recieveStarted)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, confSettings.PollInterval, 0));
    }
  }
}

private void SendNewMail()
{
  while(sendStarted)
  {
    //Payload....

    if (sendStarted)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, confSettings.PollInterval, 0));
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: A `StackOverflowException` is often caused by recursing too deep, or by circular instantiations. Are you using recursion anywhere?

Comment: "each thread loops forever"<--post that code here

Comment: HAve managed to solve it by creating the threads as static...

Comment: @Jan that sounds like burying the problem rather than fixing it...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a recursion problem, as the exception is thrown on the first instance? will try and post the code later. tx for the interest so far. Too much to paste as is, will cut it down to size...

Comment: @Jan de Jader, code posted by you works fine. May be the problem is in the "//PayLoad..." block or anywhere else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you utlize any heavy-weight library for tasks like DownloadNewMail and SendNewMail? For example I encountered StackOverflows when running large jobs using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package. Try running the same workload sequentially inside a command-line application to see if the issue persists.

Comment: As suggested the payload seems very heavy for a simple threading thingy. Am looking at Quatz jobs instead... Although it seems there is an issue using it in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 8):

Try to check callstack lenght in your code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Hop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception - {0}", e);
        }
    }

    static void Hop()
    {
        CheckStackTrace();
        Hip();
    }

    static void Hip()
    {
        CheckStackTrace();
        Hop();
    }

    static void CheckStackTrace()
    {
        StackTrace s = new StackTrace();
        if (s.FrameCount > 50)
            throw new Exception("Big stack!!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are having trouble following the flow of your application's code execution, try logging the entrance of methods with a timestamp and threadid.

Also, You can't catch the exception because it is a StackOverflowException.

See msdn: "Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, users are advised to write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example, if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state condition to terminate the recursive loop. "

Comment: I remember seeing that post on MSDN and thinking "wow... were people catching StackOverflowExceptions to break out of recursive loops?!"